# How to log data after calling function

Tags: reactjs

```
    class WorldMap extends React.Component { 
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {

            }
        }

            getGeography(){
              let url = FormatUrl(`/api/category/sov-geography/`)
              fetch(url)
              .then(res => res.json())
              .then(res => {
                localStorage.setItem("india", res['india'])
                localStorage.setItem("us", res['us'])
                localStorage.setItem("uk", res['uk'])
              })
            }



         customComponentDidMount(){
            this.getGeography()
            console.log(localStorage.getItem('us'))
         }
        }
```

Here i am fetching data from one api and storing the same data in localStorage()
But when i am logging the data from localStorage() after calling this.getGeography() function
i am getting null data.

I thing function is calling later .
Is there any way to fix this.??

PLease have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the promise that fetch creates in the `getGeography` function like so:

```
getGeography() {
    let url = FormatUrl(`/api/category/sov-geography/`)

    return fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
          localStorage.setItem("india", res['india'])
          localStorage.setItem("us", res['us'])
          localStorage.setItem("uk", res['uk'])
        });
}
```

This means `getGeography` will return a promise which you can `.then` like so:

```
customComponentDidMount() {
    this.getGeography().then(() => {
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('us'))
    });
}
```